# Hosting website subfolder on separate domain

Tags: iis, networking, dns

We have 2 web applications what we want to be installed on different IIS servers. But we want what user can access one by address www.test.com and second by www.test.com/directory

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible, unless you have a front-end "reverse proxy" which receives all queries and dispatches them to the relevant server.

Alternatively you could arrange for the main server to HTTP redirect all queries for www.example.com/directory to (e.g.) www2.example.com/directory, although obviously that's then exposing a second hostname and URL for that content.

Comment: The front-end dispatcher is indeed a good idea. With Apache (I know, the OP uses IIS), it is quite simple to configure. It allows you to keep your internal architecture private (not for security but for naming consistency).